how to deny access to my opencart website from china ip address?
how to deny access to my opencart website from china ip address?
my opencart website are located in a VPS ,whose system is debian10,apache2.4,php7.3
i went to https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker and select "firewall list by country" ,and then at the "download list" ,i select "china" for country option ,"IPV4" for IP version, "Apache2.4 .htaccess deny"for Output Format
and the download to get the code,and added these code to the bottom of .htaccess,
but it seems not work.
what should i do?
sincerely

Can you please show your configuration in .htaccess?

if you use cloudflare then blocking visitors from specific country is easy
check this: https://thedomainrobot.com/blog/how-to-enable-the-cloudflare-block-country/
